# Is it common to maximize correlation between response variable and a combination of explanatory variables as a first model?

Tags: regression, correlation, linear-model

I am doing a linear regression project and in the exploration part I did something I was asked to explain in more detail... There are only 4 variables: 1 response variable and 3 explanatory variables.

At the beginning of the study I made a correlations plot and it turned out that variable 2 had the highest correlation with the response variable. Then I computed `cor(response,var2-var3*var4)`. And then I tweaked the parameter $A$ in the expression `var1-A*var2*var3` using the `optimize` function to maximize the function `cor(response,var1-A*var2*var3)`.

The thing is, later I fitted a model with `lm(response ~ var2+var3:var4)` and it produced a formula of the type `a+b*var2+c*var3*var4`, which gave exactly the same correlation with the response variable. And the scatterplot is the same up to a symmetry and translation.

Is maximizing correlation even a good method? Is it equivalent to the least squares method used in R?

This was part of an "initial model" and later I used step wise selection and found a better model (although the sum of squares of the final model was 20% lower on a population of 43)

Comment: I suggest visually inspecting scatterplots of all input variables versus the response to determine if there is any obvious data transform, such ass log or exp, that might help in the regression.

Comment: Yes I have done that, there does not seem to be anything.

Answer (score 2):

1. Most importantly, it's not recommended practice to "maximize correlation". At least not by fitting models haphazardly. It is prone to overfitting. If the covariates are centered/scaled, the top regressor(s) selected by LASSO will be chosen on the basis of largest (partial) correlations.
2. `cor(response,var2-var3*var4)` and the correlation between the predictions from `lm(response ~ var2+var3:var4)` and the response should be different. They would only agree if the regression coefficients were 1 for the first-order effect and -1 for the product term. We would never expect to see that in a data analysis.

Comment: It's `cor(response,var2-A*var3*var4)`, there is the A parameter, and the correlations are exactly the same.

Is there some simple model that I could include before starting to fit using stepwise selection?

Comment: @JohnCataldo that is different. There exists an A to reproduce the results of the `lm` (Hint: cor(aX+bZ, Y) = cor(X + b/(a+b)Z, Y)), optimization will give you `ls` results. Stepwise model selection has been heavily discredited by most statisticians nowadays. If you choose this method, there's no "ideal" start point that can be universally recommended in all situations. You can start a forward or backward model selection at any point (between a null and fully adjusted model), but the results are only as good as your guess.

Comment: errata: cor(aX+bZ, Y) = cor(X+ b/aZ, Y)